# Excel / Word VBA : Variable String (A sentence) copy to Winword and how to part of character should be bold / change colors

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have to copy a sentence from excel to winword file.
Could I get the data in the Excel column B & C and copy data with bolded data(B) but not bold data(c) in Winword Table ?

**For example :**

In Excel : The blanket description will be shown.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID | Case Type | Location | Description | Case handle by |
| 2 | S001 | Lost and Found | 1st Floor Lobby | A wallet was found | Alan |
| 3 | S002 | Property Damaged | 2nd Floor Lobby | The defected floor tiles was found. | Keith |

[image]

**Preferred show on In Word Table :**

(Row 1)
(Column 2):  **Lost and Found (Bold & Color Red)** at 1st Floor Lobby (Not bold and Color Black)
(Next Para) A wallet was found

(Row 1)(Column 3)  Alan

(Row 2 - Blank)

(Row 3)(Column 2)  **Property Damaged (Bold & Color Blue)** at 2nd Floor Lobby (Not bold and Color Black)
(Next Para) The defected floor tiles was found.

(Row 3)(Column 3)  Keith

[image]

**VBA Code:**

```
With table(1) 
     Column B2.characters(Start:=1, Length:=Column B2).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
     Column B2.characters(Start:=1, Length:=Column B2).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
     .cell(1, 1).Range.Text = (Column B2) & " at " & (Column C2) & Chr(13) & (Column D2)
     .cell(1, 2).Range.Text = (Column E2)
     .cell(1, 3).Range.Text = ""

     Column B3.characters(Start:=1, Length:=Column B3).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
     Column B3.characters(Start:=1, Length:=Column B3).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
     .cell(1, 4).Range.Text = (Column B3 (Bold & Blue)) & " at " & (Column C3) & Chr(13) & (Column D3)
     .cell(1, 5).Range.Text = (Column E3)
     .cell(1, 3).Range.Text = ""
End with
```

Comment: Are u looking for Word VBA or Excel VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the contents directly in a Word document is a straightforward approach, eliminating the need to copy Excel cell formats to Word. Assumes there is a table in Word document.

***Note***: The provided code is written in Word VBA.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Excel2Word()
    ' Word VBA code
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlWK As Object
    Dim arrData, sPath
    Dim ExcelFile As String, sShtName As String
    Dim oDoc As Document, oTab As Table, oRange As Range
    sPath = ThisDocument.Path & "\"
    ExcelFile = "Data.xlsx" ' Modify as needed
    sShtName = "Sheet1"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile)
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks(ExcelFile)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If xlWK Is Nothing Then Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile)
        If xlWK Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, bFlag
    ' Load Excel table
    arrData = xlWK.Sheets(sShtName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    xlWK.Close False
    ' Close Excel App is needed
    '    xlApp.Quit
    j = 2
    If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get the first table on Active word document
        Set oTab = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        ' Loop through Excel table
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            ' Case ID
            oTab.Cell(j, 1).Range.Text = arrData(i, 1)
            ' Description
            With oTab.Cell(j, 2).Range
                .Text = arrData(i, 2) & " at " & arrData(i, 3) & ":" & Chr(13) & arrData(i, 4)
                .MoveEnd wdCharacter, Len(arrData(i, 2)) - Len(.Text) + 1
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.ColorIndex = IIf(bFlag, wdBlue, wdRed)
                bFlag = Not bFlag
            End With
            ' Case handle by
            oTab.Cell(j, 3).Range.Text = arrData(i, 5)
            j = j + 2
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am reading and learning the coding. Is that process under Word VBA ?

Could you tell me how to work the coding under Excel VBA ?

For Example. I create a button and I click in excel. Then the code will generate a Word file report for me (Specially the reporting in blue & Red colors & bold the sentence)

Comment: `The provided code is written in Word VBA.`. You haven't answered my last question which is under your post yesterday. So nobody know you are looking for Excel or Word code. Please provide detail about `generate a Word file report`.

Comment: There are many sample to copy data from Excel to Word.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560456/copy-cell-data-from-excel-to-word-vba